# .animate() with two complete functions?

Tags: jquery

I wondered about if it's possible to add two or more `complete` functions to the `.animate()` event, like this:

```
.animate(properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete][, complete][, complete])
```

because I don't want to have all the things that happened in one function. I want them separated in different `complete` functions!

Is this possible?

Comment: why not to use `.animate({properties},duration,easing,function(){func1();func2();func3();})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you could easily pass in an anonymous function that calls your two (or more) functions like this:

```
.animate(properties, function(){
    callback1();
    callback2();
});
```

Where callback1 and callback2 are functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can compose your callback functions into a single one (note the use of [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) in order to call the functions in the same context as the original callback):

```
$("selector").animate(properties, duration, easing, function() {
    complete1.apply(this);
    complete2.apply(this);
    complete3.apply(this);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the new [$.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) facility to group all your callbacks into a single object:

```
var animateCallbacks = $.Callbacks();
animateCallbacks.add([complete1, complete2, complete3]);

$("selector").animate(properties, duration, easing, function() {
    animateCallbacks.fireWith(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No is not possible :-).
The quickly way is call two function in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) only mentiones one callback function. It might work to use more than one, but that behavior could also change without notice, so you shouldn't use it anyway.

You can just put function calls in an anonymous function. Example:

```
 $('.moving').animate({ height: '20px' }, function() {
   callback1();
   callback2();
   callback3();
 });
```